# Phase difference between source voltage and inductor voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, inductor, electromagnetism, inductance

What will be the phase difference between the source voltage and the inductor voltage? Will the two voltages be in phase or will be out of phase. How much out of phase they will be?

Note that there is no[image] resistance in the circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phase difference between voltages is \$0\$ because you're literally forcing the voltage across inductor to be same as the source voltage.

Are there really two different measurements here? How would you go about measuring both the voltages. Where would you place the oscilloscope probe for each?

Comment: Lenz law says that the induced voltage in the inductor will be equal and opposite to the source voltage. Will that not make the induced and source voltage out of phase.

Comment: Lenz's law says that the induced voltage opposes the change in *current* through the inductor, not voltage.

Comment: Here, Lenz's law requires that the voltages be in same phase. Suppose initially the current through inductor is \$0\$. Then suddenly you put a voltage source across the inductor. Now the lenz's law doesn't allow the inductor to change it's current immediately. So inductor momentarily induces the SAME emf as the source emf across it's terminals so that the current will remain \$0\$

Comment: Thanks alot. One more thing please. So whenever there  in change in source voltage there will  always be an equal and opposite inphase induced voltage across the inductor to block the current. So how will the current flow in that circuit?

Comment: Inductor is a passive element, it cannot block the current forever. Current through the inductor is given by  \$i(t) = \frac{1}{L} \int_0^t v(t) dt\$. Notice here that the current at \$t=0\$ is \$0\$, no matter what the voltage is.

Comment: please answer this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105827/discussion-between-becca-becca-and-alex).

Comment: Ok its passive but still with each change in input voltage there is a corresponding change in inductuctor which is equal and opposite to source. So how can the current flow?